# Reasons for Column as Included

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, index-tuning

We have a simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM E 
 WHERE E_CUS_ID = CUS_ID 
   AND E_DATE_OPENED IS NOT NULL 
   AND E_DATE_OPENED < DATEADD(DAY, 7, E_DATE_SENT)
```

`SQL Server SSMS` suggests the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_EMAIL_4
    ON [dbo].[EMAIL] ([E_CUS_ID],[E_DATE_OPENED])
INCLUDE ([E_DATE_SENT])
```

To cover optimally, I would have assumed it would include `E_DATE_SENT` as a key column since it's in the `WHERE` clause.

May I ask what are some of the reasons SQL Server might use to decide whether the column should be a Key or an Included column?

I'm hoping to learn how to make better choices myself about column placement.

As a bit of a strange oddity, if I modify this query to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM E 
 WHERE E_CUS_ID = 1912 
   AND E_DATE_OPENED < DATEADD(DAY, 7, E_DATE_SENT)
```

Which I would assume produces identical output as a NULL date would never evaluate to true in the next condition anyway, SSMS changes its suggestion to this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_EMAIL_4
    ON [dbo].[EMAIL] ([E_CUS_ID])
INCLUDE ([E_DATE_SENT],[E_DATE_OPENED])
```

During performance improvement, I was going to remove this `IS NOT NULL`clause from the query anyway, so which index should I create? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: [Missing index requests aren't smart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345485(v=sql.105)). At all. To put it mildly. I like to think of it as that it doesn't have a lot of CPU cycles to produce the recommendations.

However, in this case there is a logic to the recommendations. Consider this predicate:

E_DATE_OPENED < DATEADD(DAY, 7, E_DATE_SENT)

An index cannot be SEEKed for it, since you basically compare the values between two different columns.

The reson that E_DATE_OPENED is in the key for the first example is that it includes below predicate:

E_DATE_OPENED IS NOT NULL

For above, an index can definitely be SEEKed; hence it makes sense to have that column in the key.

Comment: To add some additional detail, DATE_SENT is in the index as an included column so that it will be a covering index instead of further invoking a key lookup to get the data.  It's not necessary to make it part of the keys of the index (which would involve sorting on that additional data)

Comment: I believe I understand. To confirm, if I were to change this to E_DATE_OPENED < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it could be SEEKed?

Comment: That is correct.